# Firebase Cost when reading an image of multiple sizes

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

In reference to the query bellow, am I charged for every read I make to firebase storage in this manner.

`var storageRef = firebase.storage.ref("folderName/file.jpg")` `storageRef.getDownloadURL();`

Usually I attach the downloadurl to the document that I want the image to be linked to(meaning I only pay for one read when retrieving that file). but in my current project I want to have multiple sizes of the same image so that approach wont work. so I was thinking of using the above approach in this manner eg.`firebase.storage.ref("folderName/file_200x200.jpg").getDownloadURL(); or firebase.storage.ref("folderName/file_300x300.jpg").getDownloadURL();`(for example on a mobile device I would like to read a different image size than on a home computer) what are the draw backs(cost,speed etc.) of using such a strategy.

basically what I am try to ask is, when I read a document from firestore and use the the above query to display an image does that count as two reads?, will images still be cached using such an approach?.

If possible can you also point me to any resources that do something similar.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't read an image yet, so it won't incur any cost on Firebase Storage.

Comment: how would you suggest one goes about solving such a problem????